# Unchecked the Checkbox while looping threw array in for loop

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop, checkbox

I have the Check box of all the week days.
User Simply unchecks the day which he/she don't want to check. I save the days in comma separated string in the database as `1,2,4,5`.
I get the string back properly from DB.

**The Problem**

I am not able to uncheck the days which user uncheck before. 
Or I say I want to display only the checked days as checked and want to uncheck the days which is not checked by use.

**What is have tried so far?**

I have created an array from the string by using `split`.

After getting an array I use For loop to uncheck the checkbox but it did not work.

But I My Monday checkbox is getting uncheck.

```js
var working_day_string = '1,2,4,5'; 
var working_day_array = working_day_string.split(',');

for (i=0;i<working_day_array.length;i++)
{ 
   if(working_day_array[i] != '1'){
       $('#monday').prop('checked', false);
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-10">
 <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="monday" name="working_days[]" value="1" checked>
  <label for="monday"> Monday </label>
 </div>

 <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="tuesday" name="working_days[]" value="2" checked>
  <label for="tuesday"> Tuesday  </label>
 </div>

 <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="wednesday" name="working_days[]" value="3" checked>
  <label for="wednesday"> Wednesday  </label>
 </div>

 <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="thursday" name="working_days[]" value="4" checked>
  <label for="thursday"> Thursday </label>
 </div>
 <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="friday" name="working_days[]" value="5" checked>
  <label for="friday"> Friday  </label>
 </div>
 <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="saturday" name="working_days[]" value="6" checked>
  <label for="saturday"> Saturday  </label>
 </div>
 <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="sunday" name="working_days[]" value="7" checked>
  <label for="sunday"> Sunday  </label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `working_day_array[i] != '1' ? $('#monday').prop('checked', false) : '';` should be an `if (...) { ... }` and not an abused conditional/ternary operator

Comment: Sorry Sir, @Andreas I am not getting you properly, could you please elaborate more about what you are saying. Thanks

Comment: The conditional/ternary operator is meant to return one of two values depending on the condition in the first part. Your script does "return" a value but you're not using it. Instead the only action of the `?:` operator is to set a property of a DOM node, hence this should be done with a simple `if` instead: `if (working_day_array[i] != '1') { $('#monday').prop('checked', false); }`

Comment: Thanks @Andreas I will surely keep that in mind. I have edited my question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```js
var working_day_string = '1,2,4,5';
var working_day_array = working_day_string.split(',');
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false); //reset all checkboxes
$.each(working_day_array, function(i, day) {
  $('input[value="' + day + '"]').prop('checked', true); //check the box from the array, note: you need to add a class to your checkbox group to only select the checkboxes, right now it selects all input elements that have the values in the array 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-10">

    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="monday" name="working_days[]" value="1" checked>
        <label for="monday"> Monday </label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tuesday" name="working_days[]" value="2" checked>
        <label for="tuesday"> Tuesday  </label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="wednesday" name="working_days[]" value="3" checked>
        <label for="wednesday"> Wednesday  </label>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="thursday" name="working_days[]" value="4" checked>
        <label for="thursday"> Thursday </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="friday" name="working_days[]" value="5" checked>
        <label for="friday"> Friday  </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="saturday" name="working_days[]" value="6" checked>
        <label for="saturday"> Saturday  </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="sunday" name="working_days[]" value="7" checked>
        <label for="sunday"> Sunday  </label>
    </div>

</div>
```